# Exception in connecting Xmpp chat app with server

Tags: connection, xmpp

my code is

```
try {
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(hostname, portno, "");
                 conn = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                conn.connect();
                } 
            catch (XMPPException e)
            {
                throw new ProtocolException(e.toString());
            }
```

How to resolve this problem?

> 07-23 11:54:08.126: W/dalvikvm(19805): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   method 3144: Ljavax/swing/SwingUtilities;.invokeLater
>   (Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V 07-23 11:54:08.126: D/dalvikvm(19805): VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006 07-23 11:54:08.126: D/dalvikvm(19805):
>   VFY: dead code 0x0009-0009 in
>   Lorg/jivesoftware/smackx/debugger/EnhancedDebugger;.userHasLogged
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)V 07-23 11:54:09.507: W/System.err(19805):
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 07-23 11:54:09.517:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 07-23
>   11:54:09.517: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 07-23
>   11:54:09.527: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPConnection.java:1027)
>   07-23 11:54:09.527: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:850)
>   07-23 11:54:09.547: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:834)
>   07-23 11:54:09.577: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1276)
>   07-23 11:54:09.607: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   com.src.protocol.XMPPProtocolManager.connect(XMPPProtocolManager.java:116)
>   07-23 11:54:09.607: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   com.src.screen.Login.onClick(Login.java:80) 07-23 11:54:09.607:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532) 07-23 11:54:09.607:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293) 07-23 11:54:09.617:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 07-23
>   11:54:09.617: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 07-23
>   11:54:09.627: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 07-23 11:54:09.627:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310) 07-23
>   11:54:09.637: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-23
>   11:54:09.637: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-23 11:54:09.647:
>   W/System.err(19805):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   07-23 11:54:09.647: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 07-23
>   11:54:09.657: W/System.err(19805):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-23 11:54:09.657:
>   W/System.err(19805): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax.swing.JTabbedPane 07-23 11:54:09.667: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.EnhancedDebugger.createDebug(EnhancedDebugger.java:158)
>   07-23 11:54:09.667: W/System.err(19805):  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.EnhancedDebugger.(EnhancedDebugger.java:147)
>   07-23 11:54:09.667: W/System.err(19805):  ... 19 more 07-23
>   11:54:09.677: E/[Login.java] : onConnection :(19805): 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-23 11:54:12.190: E/[Login.java] :
>   login :(19805):  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to
>   server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown if

```
InvocationTargetException - if the underlying method throws an exception.
```

So if the method, that has been invoked with reflection API, throws an exception (runtime exception for example), the reflection API will wrap the exception into an InvocationTargetException.